# Why are the offsets produced by arrow::ListArray::offsets() interspersed with zeros?

Tags: c++, parquet, python-polars, apache-arrow

I am trying to read the data in a parquet file containing lists of floats using C++.

I produced a simple parquet file using the following python code:

```
import polars as pl
import struct
import random
import pyarrow.parquet as pq

floatlist = []
for _ in range(10):
  lstlen = random.choice([3, 4, 5])
  floatlist.append([random.random() for _ in range(lstlen)])

df = pl.DataFrame({"float_list": floatlist})

file_out_path = 'test.parquet'
df.write_parquet(file_out_path)
print(pl.read_parquet(file_out_path))
```

Result is the very reasonable looking:

```
shape: (10, 1)
┌──────────────────────────────────┐
│ float_list                       │
│ ---                              │
│ list[f64]                        │
╞══════════════════════════════════╡
│ [0.863913, 0.831073, 0.264516]   │
│ [0.51377, 0.434267, … 0.131684]  │
│ [0.978071, 0.251396, … 0.142218] │
│ [0.495616, 0.628793, 0.434872]   │
│ …                                │
│ [0.19035, 0.68318, … 0.778707]   │
│ [0.103636, 0.08755, … 0.526014]  │
│ [0.803863, 0.382698, … 0.728598] │
│ [0.323969, 0.412751, … 0.12993]  │
└──────────────────────────────────┘
```

Now I try to read the same test.parquet file in C++ using the following code:

```
void read_parquet(std::string file_name) {

    arrow::Status st;
    std::shared_ptr<arrow::io::ReadableFile> infile;

    PARQUET_ASSIGN_OR_THROW(infile, arrow::io::ReadableFile::Open(file_name));

    std::unique_ptr<parquet::arrow::FileReader> reader;
    PARQUET_THROW_NOT_OK(parquet::arrow::OpenFile(infile, arrow::default_memory_pool(), &reader));

    std::shared_ptr<arrow::RecordBatchReader> record_batch_reader;
    st = reader->GetRecordBatchReader(&record_batch_reader);
    std::shared_ptr<arrow::RecordBatch> record_batch;

    while (true) {
      arrow::Status status = record_batch_reader->ReadNext(&record_batch);

      if (!status.ok() || record_batch == nullptr) {
          break;  // Exit the loop if there are no more batches or if an error occurs
      }

      std::cout << "Num records in batch: " << record_batch->num_rows() << std::endl;
      auto floatlist = std::static_pointer_cast<arrow::ListArray>(record_batch->column(0));
      std::cout << "Length of floatlist: " << floatlist->length() << std::endl;
      std::cout << "Offsets: " << floatlist->offsets()->ToString() << std::endl;
    
      auto floatlist_vals = std::static_pointer_cast<arrow::DoubleArray>(floatlist->values());
      const double* floatlist_ptr = floatlist_vals->raw_values();

      for (int64_t i = 0; i < record_batch->num_rows(); i++) {

          std::cout << "\n\n";

          if ( floatlist->IsValid(i) ) {
            std::cout << "Row " << i << " IsValid" << std::endl;
          }
          if ( floatlist->IsNull(i) ) {
            std::cout << "Row " <<  i << " IsNull" << std::endl;
          }
                  
          const double* first = floatlist_ptr + floatlist->value_offset(2*i);
          const double* last = floatlist_ptr + floatlist->value_offset(2*(i + 1));
          if (last > first) {
            std::vector<double> flst(first, last);
            std::cout << "Length of flst is: " << flst.size() << std::endl;
            for (size_t i = 0; i < flst.size(); i++) {
              std::cout << flst[i] << ", ";
            }
            std::cout << std::endl;
          }
      }
    }
}
```

What I found is that:

```
std::cout << "Offsets: " << floatlist->offsets()->ToString() << std::endl;
```

generates the following output:

```
Offsets: [
  0,
  0,
  3,
  0,
  7,
  0,
  12,
  0,
  15,
  0,
  19
]
```

Some examples suggested I could recover the data by using:

```
const double* first = floatlist_ptr + floatlist->value_offset(i);
const double* last = floatlist_ptr + floatlist->value_offset(i + 1);
std::vector<double> flst(first, last);
```

But this obviously crashes due to the zeros in the list of value_offsets.
I could get this to work using:

```
const double* first = floatlist_ptr + floatlist->value_offset(2*i);
const double* last = floatlist_ptr + floatlist->value_offset(2*(i + 1));
if (last > first) {
    std::vector<double> flst(first, last);
}
```

My questions:

1. Why is the list of offsets interspersed with zeros?
2. Why are we led to believe that the number of offsets is num_rows + 1, but in actual fact

```
arrow::BaseListArray<arrow::ListType>::value_offset(int64_t i)
```

accepts index values well above num_rows + 1. In fact you need to go at least up to 2*num_rows to get all your data?

3. Is this how arrow along with parquet always work? Will this pattern hold if my parquet file has columns with ~100000 rows?

Comment: Could it be that your data is stored with 64 bit offsets, but you are trying to interpret offsets as 32 bit ints? What happens if you use `LargeListArray` instead of `ListArray`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Pola.rs defaults to `Type::LARGE_LIST` to physically represent the logical list type, so when you get the data from the file written by Pola.rs you should cast it to `LargeListArray` instead of `ListArray`.

The zeroes you see are the extra 32-bit half of a 64-bit offset that could fit on a 32-bit offset.

To get debug-build checks on casts, you can use `arrow::internal::checked_cast<T>` or `assert(array.type_id() == arrow::Type::LIST_TYPE)` before casting to `ListArray`.

Comment: Thank you. This was very helpful. If you could answer my next question:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77566770/reading-a-column-of-strings-from-a-parquet-file-into-c-string-variables
that would be most fabulous.