# Reading a column of strings from a parquet file into C++ string variables

Tags: c++, parquet, python-polars, apache-arrow

I have a parquet file which I have created using the python polars package. It has a single column of variable length strings that looks like:

```
┌──────────┐
│ str_list │
│ ---      │
│ str      │
╞══════════╡
│ ALV5     │
│ SMGWX    │
│ NEGOT    │
│ S2U0S    │
│ …        │
│ KFO      │
│ LJ3J     │
│ PCY6O    │
│ GQ0W7    │
└──────────┘
```

I try to read this file using C++ into string variables but I am not sure what I should cast it to since the type turns out to be LARGE_STRING:

```
assert(record_batch->column(0)->type_id() == arrow::Type::LARGE_STRING)
```

is true.

I can do

```
auto strlist = std::static_pointer_cast<arrow::LargeStringArray>(record_batch->column(0));
```

but I cannot find any member function of strlist that lets me copy the strings to my own string variable.

Comment: `BaseBinaryArray` (the super-super-class of `LargeStringArray`) has an overloaded `operator[]` as well as a `std::string GetString(int64_t i)`. Don't forget you can actually read header files with your eyes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `LargeStringArray::GetView(i)` to get a `std::string_view` so you don't have to heap-allocate a `std::string` for every string in the array.